# Should "guest of honour" be capitalised?

Tags: nouns, capitalization

> The Principal will invite the guest of honour to give the National Day message at 9 o'clock.

Is the *guest of honour* capitalised?

Comment: Probably not, but it might depend on the context.

Comment: As an aside, capitalization is not punctuation. Capitalization is capitalization.

Comment: In your example, 'National Day' obviously needs the capitals. 'The Principal' is obviously capitalised because this is a reference to an actual person by an equivalent of their name (Mrs Johnston, say). If the reference were generic, we'd put 'The principal / president / king'. It depends on whether 'guest of honour' is being used as an equivalent for 'Mrs Obama' say, or generically.

Answer (score 3):

Either "guest of honour" or "Guest of Honour" is appropriate. There is no universal rule for capitalizing the term. If you are publishing this phrase you should check your organization's style guide or past examples. Otherwise, choose which variation looks most pleasing in the specific context.

Comment: Either *both are* appropriate or *either is* -- not ***either are***.

Comment: @Drew: Eh, you are right. This is a common mistake in my region and I picked up the habit. Fixed.

Comment: In 'normal' writing capitals would be hard to justify but on an invitation or menu or order of service for any kind of special event - and why else would there be a guest of honour - at least many people will expect the capitals…

Answer (score 0):

Despite how I capitalize it, the terms always seems to be in lower-case on the dictionary websites shown in this Google search and the only real exception being [the film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guest_of_Honour);

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=guest+of+honour

Comment: What is the *Despite how I capitalize it* bit about?

Comment: @virmaior I tried capitalizing different words in the phrase to check the websites weren't doing something clever like just showing me the definition exactly how I capitalized it

Comment: Google is not generally case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

If we intend to emphasize upon or separate the "guest of honor" from the invitees. 
No CAP rule is suggested anywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

I would capitalize if the same document *names* the guest of honor (pardon converting to AE spelling), and likewise for Teacher of the Year, etc. In that case, I would treat as a proper noun. If this is general instructions, no.